# If a user leaves, are votes reversed?

Tags: support

Really just curious, but if a user is removed "forcefully", his or her votes are undone. That is completely understandable.

What however if a user closes his or her account deliberately, are his or her down & upvotes reversed as well?

Comment: See https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/268608/306534

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, by default the votes are removed. Sometimes we can request that SE does a special deletion and keep the votes, but I am unaware of the exact criterion.

Comment: If someone like Oli would leave, that would be a "disruptive" leave and these are not reversed.  Do you want me to try and leave to see whether the cut-out is above or below 10K?  **;-)**

Comment: @Fabby The "cut" is not reputation based. It probably has more to do with the deletion reason and number of votes.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to depend on how disruptive the vote removal would be.

Here's how it works:

```
There are two thresholds:
    Number of votes cast by the user being deleted
    Number of people affected significantly by those votes

The exact values of those thresholds don't particularly matter; they're pretty low, but not so low that you could hit them easily while still hiding fraudulent activity.
If either threshold is exceeded, deletion is held up until someone reviews it. Otherwise, deletion proceeds and any votes are discarded.
If, during review, it becomes apparent that the user is or ever was involved in voting fraud, the votes are discarded as they would normally be.
Otherwise, the votes are preserved.
```

Source: [Don't throw away all votes when a user is deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125740/dont-throw-away-all-votes-when-a-user-is-deleted/268608#268608)