# Deactivate account, share reputation

Tags: discussion

If and when I want to deactivate my Ask Ubuntu account, how would I share my reputation with other AU members before I deactivate?

Comment: What do you defined as 'deserving' AU members ? You have posted several questions. If you are satisfied with the answers and the help you got, you can put bounty on them to share your reputation with the members you think they "deserve it".

Comment: Someone told me not to make any decisions when hurt or angry and so I won't. Let me just disappear for sometime then I'll be back. For now I'll just re-edit the question wordings to fit the situation.

Comment: I'm glad to see you didn't part yet (I saw a recent answer of yours) :)

Comment: @kos Sure. I was just going through some tough times - heartbreaks are awful. But am good now. No worries :)

Comment: I recommend migrating this to Meta.StackExchange.com

Comment: @BenC.R.Leggiero The question is perfectly fine here. I see no reason to migrate it.

Comment: @Seth Alright. I was just hoping we could get it to a place where more people on SE would see it, since it's good knowledge for us all.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

No. The best you can do is offer bounties on questions with deserving but underrecognized answers. That way, you can give your reputation in large chunks to users that deserve it and also highlight some worthwhile questions.

Comment: I think, thid is a really good idea.

Answer (score 14):

You add bounties to *answers* you feel deserve extra reputation. But:

- 3 at a time
- 500 per bounty max
- 48 hour limit between starting and assigning a bounty.

So yes, you can spend the week assigning your reputation away. Of course you can spend longer and do it in smaller chunks.

But don't target one person please. Like any voting it should be on the merit of the post, not who posted it.

Comment: Isn't it so that votes (and bounties) are reversed when a user deactivates his account? See http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/14128/if-a-user-leaves-are-votes-reversed

Comment: @JacobVlijm https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/268608/306534

Comment: @Ravan Ah, good to know, thanks!